# How to implement lazy loading in a div with a card?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, lazy-loading

During my research I saw several tutorials on how to create lazy loading with images and iframes. However I could not find any tutorial on how to do this in a div with any other type of content.

I have a div that calls a google tag manager script, I want to make this div load only when the person scrolls on my page.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Listen to page scroll, as soon as it triggers, load your div and remove this listener

Comment: I'm not sure it applies to divs and such. However, if you wanted, you can do it manually with websockets, ajax, or similar.

Comment: Have you looked at Intersection Observer API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0):

Comment from @bo-wahlstrøm  is most precisely the route you need to go with. Here is basic idea, lazy loading is hack and it can be applied on almost anything! yes that is correct!

how so?
suppose image tag which has src attribute. so does JS script etc. Browser are fanatically hard wired to fetch anything when value of these attributes change.

So what we do is on initial load we keep **`<img src="">`** empty but add another data attribute which has no fanatic effect what so ever. **`<img src="" data-src="myimage.jpg">`**

Once you get hand of the Intersection Observer we simply inject src value once the user is so and so pixel close to observer box e.g. 100px from bottom or what ever.
Thus  **`<img src="" data-src="myimage.jpg">`** would become **`<img src="myimage.jpg" data-src="myimage.jpg">`**.

Do the same with script src attribute and it should do the trick. heck you can do the same to even css url property.

That is all there is to it really.

Comment: Glad it did work out, always keep in mind UI effects more of conceptual played in time line. we now days call it perceived impression or impact ...it does not matter how it technicality went under the hood. Lazy loading is just one of such perceived impression to user that site is fast loading believing everything loaded in flash as normal, only we didnt load anything that was not in first browser view port.

Comment: Just an added note in old days lazy loading was actually spun to popularity to reduce serve calls  aka save server bandwidth for resources that did not weren't even seen by the user. Now days browsers have gone step further to implement look ahead feature they kind of do the same lazy loading and try to figure out where user will go and fetch resources and victoriously cache resources to fast load things.

Comment: Now final word form user interface experience perspective, one of the benefits of lazy loading is non blocking feature. It does not block DOM pain or something else. browser can only fetch around 3-6 images at a time on fly, so if your google script is taking long then lazy load else dont (It will be cached). Now days game is to get user to interact with the page as soon as possible hence google's 3 second loading rule. This where money worth is. .